# Gorenstein implies Poincaré duality

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

In [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82458627.pdf) of Felix, Halperin and Thomas, it is stated that

> When $H^* (X; \mathbb{k})$ is finite dimensional, we have that $X$ is
> Gorenstein at $\mathbb{k}$ if and only if $H^* (X;\mathbb{k})$ satisfies Poincare duality.

where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field.

The definition of *Gorenstein* here is that

$$\text{dim Ext}_{C^* (X;\mathbb{k})}(\mathbb{k},C^* (X;\mathbb{k})) = 1.$$

I am unable to tell from the context whether this is a result which is proven in the paper, or whether it is supposed to be clear.

Either way, what is the proof of this result?

Comment: It looks like this is the material in section 3, specficially Theorems 3.1 and 3.6.